# Use a html page as a custom section in Umbraco 7 without a tree

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a HTML page that I want to show in a custom section in Umbraco 7.

I want to do this without having any tree within that section, as everything is already handled within the html file - It is being placed into the Umbraco back end for convenient access.

So far I have implemented IApplication which gets the section to show as expected. I did have a tree with a single node (Inheriting from BaseTree, making this a legacy section), however, I want to make full use of the space available and just load in my html file and have no tree showing.

Removing the nodes from the BaseTree Render method hides the panel that shows the tree, but I can't figure out how to load in the Html file as the default view for that section.

Is there an easy way to do this by essentially setting a default page to load when the user clicks into the section?

Comment: The default view is normally set in Dashboard.config:
  `<section alias="custom">
    <areas>
      <area>custom</area>
    </areas>
    <tab caption="Get Started">
      <control>/App_Plugins/CustomSection/DefaultView.html</control>
    </tab>
  </section>`

Comment: What Robert said, make sure that the <area> part contains the alias of your custom section, all in lower case. That way it should show that HTML view when you load straight into your section.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is how I did it and i'll post an answer saying that later today, unless one of you wants to post an answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Thanks Dan.  See my posted answer (containing the tip from @Tim).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the default view for a custom section in Umbraco 7 by adding a new section element to Dashboard.config as follows:

```
  <section alias="StartupCustomDashboardSection">
    <areas>
      <area>custom</area>
    </areas>
    <tab caption="Get Started">
      <control>/app_plugins/custom/defaultview.html</control>
    </tab>
  </section>
```

where the `<area>` element must contain the alias of your custom section, all in lower case.

The `<control>` element contains the path of the default html file.