# Custom Section without Tree in Umbraco CMS

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Im a relatively new programmer using Umbraco, and I've got a question for anyone who can help me.

I'm trying to do a Custom Section on the Umbraco backoffice, without having the tree.. I just want to render an angular view when the user clicks the "Section" button on the nav menu of Umbraco..

Can anyone give me a step by step tutorial on how to achieve this goal?

Comment: According to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386565/use-a-html-page-as-a-custom-section-in-umbraco-7-without-a-tree You'll have to create a custom tree with no nodes. Haven't tried this out myself

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom section in Dashboard.config located in Config folder.

As an example -

```
<section alias="CustomDashboardSection">
    <areas>
      <area>sync</area>
    </areas>
    <tab caption="CustomControl">
      <control>/App_plugins/CustomControl/Control.html</control>
    </tab>
  </section>
```

You can replace the name of the tab and control accordingly.

Hope it helps!

Thanks